# Why positive definite matrix rather than positively definite matrix?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, linear-algebra

"Positive definite matrix" is a standard term in mathematics, espeically linear algebra. Are there grammatical, linguistic, or historical reasons why it was not called "positively definite matrix"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Miller's Earliest Known Uses](http://jeff560.tripod.com/p.html) positive definite, as applied to forms, appears first in [Pierpont's Lectures On The Theory Of Functions Of Real Variables (1905)](https://archive.org/details/lecturesonthethe032088mbp/page/n1). Pierpont uses the reversed expression for numbers, e.g. "*For, if $p\neq q$, say $p > q$, then $p-q$ is a definite positive rational number; call it d*". Here "definite" and "positive" are thought as two separate characterizations rather than "definite" adverbially modifying "positive". Later he makes it explicit with forms:

> "*A form... which has always one sign, except at the origin where it necessarily vanishes, is called definite... If the sign of a definite form is positive, it is called a positive definite form; if negative, it is a negative definite form.*".

Apparently, he does not have in mind adverbial modifiers as in "positively definite" or "definitely positive".

Comment: The OED lists an even earlier one: 1904   *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **5** 464   *It is well known that there is always one such invariant, a **positive-definite** Hermitian form.*